# My attempt to show the conditions where if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b\land \lim_{y\to b}g(y)=c\implies\lim_{x\to a}(g\circ f)(x)=c$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to check if this way to prove the theorem about limits of compositions of functions is correct. Im equating logical statements but Im not sure if this formal proof is correct or I need to change some symbols.

We have some $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ where the composition of $(g\circ f)(x)$ is well defined. And we have that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$ and $\lim_{y\to b}g(y)=c$ and we want to see what is needed for $\lim_{x\to a}(g\circ f)(x)=c$.

Expanding the definition of functional limits we have:

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b\iff(\forall\varepsilon>0\,\exists\delta>0:0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-b|<\varepsilon)$$
$$\lim_{y\to b}g(y)=c\iff(\forall\gamma>0\,\exists\varepsilon>0:0<|y-b|<\varepsilon\implies |g(y)-c|<\gamma)$$
$$\lim_{x\to a}(g\circ f)(x)=c\iff(\forall\gamma>0\,\exists\delta>0:0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |(g\circ f)(x)-c|<\gamma)$$

Equating logical statements assuming that $f(x)=y$ we can see that all three only hold at once under two possible conditions:

1. If we change in the first statement $\color{red}{|f(x)-b|<\varepsilon}$ by $\color{green}{0<|f(x)-b|<\varepsilon}$ what means that exists a $\delta$-neighborhood where $\forall x\in V_{\delta}(a)\setminus\{a\}\implies f(x)\neq b$
2. If we change in the second statement $\color{red}{0<|y-b|<\varepsilon}$ by $\color{green}{|y-b|<\varepsilon}$ what means that $g(y)$ is continuous at $b$

Comment: Your observations are correct. And it is better to chose the first condition $f(x) \neq b$ instead of choosing continuity of $g$.