# Moving limit symbol when dealing with an infinite limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I recently saw a proof where the equivalence
$$
P\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(nt\ln(1+r/n))=P\exp(t\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln(1+r/n))
$$
was used. How can you justify this?

I know the theorem that states that if $f$ is continuous at $b$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=b$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f(b)$ or simply $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to a}g(x))$, but this is for when $x$ approaches a finite value $a$. What happens when $x$ tends to infinity? I know $e^x$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$--is that the condition under which the equivalence above is used? Can someone explain the difference between pushing the limit symbol through for just $x\to a$ as opposed to $x\to\infty$?

Comment: I'm on a mobile so a cant give this a full answer but you should be able to show this is justified via a epsilon delta proof.

Comment: Read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804113/my-attempt-to-show-the-conditions-where-if-lim-x-to-afx-b-land-lim-y-to). These are the conditions for composition of functions. If the limit is infinite you need to change some inequalities inside the definitions and see what happens.

Comment: One way would be to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \exp(nt \ln(1+r/n))=\lim_{a \to L} \exp(ta)$ where $L=\lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln(1+r/n)$. Then since $L$ is actually finite this goes the same as the familiar case. Do you see why this would be the case?

Comment: @Ian Yes, that is a nice manipulation to use the conventional rules. Would it work if I were to prove the following though? "Let $f$ be continuous on $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=b\in A$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(g(x))=f(b)$ or simply $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x))$"?

Comment: I think that would work yes. I also think you could probably achieve it by further composing with $1/x$, which lets you switch the $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ into $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$.